# What are the few good fonts for writing a mathematics (maths) book?

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts

I am writing a book using MS Word 2007. The book will have lots of mathematical calculations, equations, formulas, square-root symbols, squares and cube symbols, etc. and will span across algebra, polynomial equations, differentiation, integration, etc.

Can someone please suggest a few good FREE fonts that I can use conveniently in MS Word 2007 edition for writing the book?

Thanks in advance.

PS: I raised this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3299459/what-are-the-few-good-fonts-for-writing-a-mathematics-maths-book?noredirect=1#comment6787967_3299459), but users suggested that it should be asked in this forum.

Comment: What about [Liberation Serif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberation_fonts)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The author of the article
[Math Fonts in Microsoft Office](https://mrchasemath.com/2013/01/05/math-fonts-in-microsoft-office/)
has researched the issue and listed three fonts:

> - XITS Math is somewhat compatible with Times ([download here](https://github.com/khaledhosny/xits-math/downloads))
> - Asana Math is compatible with Palatino ([download here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/Asana-Math/)) and if you
>     don’t have Palatino, you can download it
>     [here](http://www.fontpalace.com/font-download/Palatino/), among other
>     places
> - Latin Modern is the LaTeX font of choice. There is a math font ([download
>     here](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/lm-math/download/index_html))
>     and a whole family of text fonts ([download
>     here](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern/download)).
>     Note: these may not look good on screen, but they look just perfect
>     when printed.

The author has provided this comparison to help choose one of the three:

---

[image]

---

Comment: Thanks @harrymc, the link that your mentioned (https://mrchasemath.com) is great...the cheatsheet and the links to shortcuts fulfills the requirement. Marking as an answer and +1.

Comment: wow, Latin Modern is almost unreadable in this screen shot!